# Sliding window with button from bottom

Tags: java, android

How to do the window like a container on screenshot?

From first it is invisible, only one button is on bottom of activity, and than user can slide this button up, the container is shown.

If the user release the button the container slides down,

[image]

if the user slide button heigher the container fill almost all activity.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) object. The problem is that it's Deprecated since API level 17.

> This class is not supported anymore. It is recommended you base your own implementation on the source code for the Android Open Source Project if you must use it in your application.

Comment: Can you explane this quote for non-english speaking user, please. What does it mean -" you base your own implementation on the source code for the Android Open Source Project if you must use it in your application"?

Comment: May be I should use something other to save space in activity.. I have an activity that contains large list of data and the user can select from this list, so I want "a busket" for him to have a look on what he already selected.